# how to unit test FP function that uses dependency

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, functional-programming

Trying to understand how functional programmers unit test functions that have dependencies without dependency injection. 
In order to unit test with mocks, you can either provide your dependency through the method signature or through a constructor/constructor-like mechanism.

so if you have function composition like this:

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

If you have `d` talking to some dependency, how does `a` get unit tested?
Where ever the dependency is kept, I'd want to have it unit tested.
I want to know what approach functional programmers take.

Comment: Main logic written with pure functions - without side effects. Side effect functions injected as function parameters.

Comment: So if I have a side effect function being passed to `d`, does that mean I have to pass it all the way down from `a`??

Comment: Not necessarily, you can build your logic pipeline with three stages: 1. gather required data 2. operate on the data 3. save data. With such approach side-effect function will remain on top level.

Comment: You might need [dependency rejection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/02/02/dependency-rejection/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unit test depenent code with proper **scoping**, **mocking**, and **dependency injection**. Let me show you what I mean.

```js
const square = x => x ** 2

const isOdd = x => x % 2 === 1

const addDependentValue = dependency => x => x + dependency.value

const mockDependency = { value: 5 }

it('filters out evens, squares, and adds value from dependency', () => {
  const output = pipe([
    filter(isOdd),
    map(square),
    map(addDependentValue(mockDependency)),
  ])([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  assert.deepEqual(output, [6, 14, 30]) // OK
})
```

We **scoped** our function `addDependentValue` so that the return could "see" the dependency (it's in scope). In our test, we **mocked** our dependency with `mockDependency`. This would enable us to derive a predictable result in our test. In a less contrived example, your mock should mirror the interface of whatever dependency you are mocking. Finally, we **inject** the `mockDependency` in our test, allowing us to reasonably test this pipeline.

> how does a get unit tested?

`a` is pure, so you can just write a simple unit test for it

```js
// if a is square
it('squares', () => {
  assert.strictEqual(square(3), 9) // OK
})
```